# Equations of gravitation in Bronstein's article

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, quantum-gravity

I'm studying Matvei Bronstein's 'Quantum theory of weak gravitational fields' and in the general remarks whilst he gives the correct expression for the Riemann-Christoffel curvature tensor in first order approximation, when he describes the equation of gravitation in empty space he sets
the Ricci tensor to zero but without including the substraction of the term with the Ricci scalar. Is this a mistake?, or for some reason I'm not understanding this also gives the correct description of gravitation in weak fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s not a mistake. If you contract

$$R_{\mu\nu}-\frac12g_{\mu\nu}R=0\tag{1}$$

you get $R=0$, so (1) implies

$$R_{\mu\nu}=0\tag{2}.$$

Similarly, (2) implies (1).

In words, a vanishing Einstein tensor is equivalent to a vanishing Ricci tensor.

The $-\frac12g_{\mu\nu}R$ in the Einstein tensor matters when the energy-momentum tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$ on the right side of Einstein’s field equations isn’t zero.

Comment: very helpful thank you !